# Jquery - How to defined user defined jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can we create user defined function in jquery like :

```
    $(selector).click(function()
   {

    })
```

Above function is already in jquery library.

if i want to create function like above one For e.g. :

```
$(selector).demo();
```

How i can create function "demo()" to which i can prefix the ***selector*** as ***$(selector).demo();***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by jQeury.fn.extend()

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    demo: function(value){
       alert(value);
    }
});
```

you can also pass **parameters** if you need, like 10 in this example.

```
$(selector).demo(10);
```

if you would like to pass a **function**

```
$.fn.extend({
        demo: function(func){
            if(typeof func === 'function')
                func();
        });
```

pass the function then you trigger it in demo

```
  $(selector).demo(function(){
      alert('test');
  });
```

hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for this...Can i pass function as parameter to demo()?

Comment: sure! in javascript function is also a object, you can parse it definetely

Comment: I add some further information for you , take a look!

Answer (score 2):

So:

```
jQuery.fn.newfunction= function() {

//code goes here

};
```

And then call:

```
$(element).newfunction();
```

[jQuery.fn.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/)